How to Develop a Dynamic Schema Handler for Scalable Dataset Management on a Website?
I'm currently working on my final project, which involves creating a website for storing, managing, and visualizing datasets uploaded by users. My inspiration for this project comes from this
https://www.gso.gov.vn/en/homepage/
While the website is designed to handle datasets from all over the world, my focus is on handling datasets specific to my city or country. Therefore, the main challenge lies in building a dynamic schema handler for these datasets.
During my research, I came across this https://docs.datacommons.org/data_model.html, which discusses the importance of having a single schema for all data, aiming for web-friendliness by aligning with widely used schemas such as Schema.org.
Although I understand that this concept is related to linked data, I'm not familiar with it or the semantic web.
I have attempted to approach it in this manner: by reading and understanding the relationships within all the defined schemas in Data Commons. However, the schemas are extensive, while my project is relatively straightforward, focusing solely on datasets specific to my country rather than globally. Consequently, I believe I should begin by constructing my own schema handler using the available datasets I possess (approximately 10-20 datasets). However, I am unsure of how to commence this process or what research I should undertake to initiate its development.
Can anyone suggest documents or tutorials that can help me delve deeper into this topic? I aim to develop my own dynamic schema handler to ensure scalability for my website, accommodating a substantial number of available datasets (although not as extensive as Data Commons).
Thank you so much !

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Further, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. Also learn how to post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.
